# How to generate supersets from a finite number of subsets efficiently

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, sets

Let $F$ be a set, for instance $\{a,b,c,d,e \}$. Suppose I have a set of subsets of cardinality two obtained from $F$:

$ ${ a,b },$\{b,c\},${a,d}

I want to create every possible set of cardinality three starting from one of these subsets of cardinality two that do not have $e$ as a member, and collect them in a set that includes all these 3-cardinality sets.

One way of doing this would be merging each set of cardinality two with a singleton subset of the original set $F$, excluding the singleton $\{e\}$.

But this procedure would be in some cases redundant, it would generate the same subset of cardinality three more then once (for instance, merging {a,b} with {d} and merging {a,d} with {b} will give me the same subset).

So one should find a way to avoid repeating useless mergings: one suggested way is considering the lexicographic order on the set $\{$$ ${ a,b },$\{b,c\},${a,d}   $\}$ and applying the following restriction:

"Merge a set $A$ of cardinality 2 with a singleton only if the element in the singleton is greater in terms of lexicographic ordering then the elements in $A$"

In this way, for instance, we avoid merging {a,d} with {b}, since d>b, but we still perform the merge of{a,b} with {d} since b<d. This is suggested to avoid repetitions.

There are two things that I do not understand and can't prove by myself:

1. The set of sets of cardinality 3 we get should be exactly the same set we get when we apply the procedure when taking into account the lexicographic restriction imposed. This could be a proof of this fact: let F3 be one of the sets of cardinality 3 we might get. Then order it lexicographically, such that {a1,a2,a3} are its elements. BUt then it can be obtained from {a1,a2} + {a3}, a merging we have done by hypothesis.
2. How can we prove that the lexicographic ordering avoids repetition in any possible cases?

Comment: One possible way is to consider binary representation for each subset. For example$\{ a,b \}$ is $11000$, $\{e\}$ is $00001$ and work on numbers.

Comment: Considering 2.: your proof for 1. already covers this. $\{a < b < c\}$ can only be created from $\{a < b\}$ and from no other set due to the lexicographic condition.